# What content needs to go in the main site faq, the first block?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

What information do you think needs to be in the header block of our FAQ?

Check out some of the FAQs of our sister sites:

https://english.stackexchange.com/faq

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq

https://photo.stackexchange.com/faq

and especially https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq

I'm soliciting suggestions of content or lists to be included. We'll mock up a suitable answer here as CW next week for discussion before making it semi-official

Answer (score 10):

### What kind of questions can I ask here?

Database Administrators - Stack Exchange is for database professionals needing expert answers on all advanced database-related topics concerning either traditional SQL RDBMS or NoSQL databases. **If you have a question about:**

- Database Administration, including [installation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installation), [provisioning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/provisioning), [scaling](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scaling), [replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replication), [migration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration), [tuning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tuning), [partitioning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partitioning), [clustering](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clustering), [referential-integrity](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/referential-integrity), [ddl](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ddl)
  <strike>Installation

  Provisioning

  Scaling

  Replication

  Migration

  Tuning

  Partitioning

  Clustering

  Referential Integrity

  Altering Database Objects</strike>
- Database Backup, Restore, Export, Import and ETL
- Database Recovery
- Data Modelling / Database Design
- Advanced programming in server-side languages built into databases, eg:
  Stored Procedures
  Triggers
- Advanced Querying, eg:
  Windowing functions
  Hierarchical data
  Dynamic SQL
  Advanced optimization
  Pivoting data

**and it is not about…**

- client-side programming questions (ask on Stack Overflow instead)
- <strike>basic SQL questions (ask on Stack Overflow instead)</strike>
- career advice, including general workplace issues
- what platform you should learn next, including which technology is better in general terms
- salary or compensation
- résumé help
- what project you should do next

**…then you're in the right place to ask your question!**

Comment: just a rough idea so flame away :)

Comment: I like this. For the "ask on ... instead" we can link to the other sites. We might also differentiate things that belong on [sf] or [su] (the latter might be phpMyAdmin or the like).

Comment: Good work Jack, covers everything I can think of so far. Could perhaps expand on the basic vs advanced by linking to existing questions on SO and dba.se?

Comment: Seems on the mark, the "Do ask about" list is a bit long though. I don't object to anything in particular though

Comment: @Ben good point, maybe the sub-lists can be collapsed into a 'show more' button like we already have on some bits of the [faq](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: @JackDouglas I was thinking exactly that, I'm not sure how the Show More things work though. If the sublists could be collapsed until the "full" entry is shown that would be great.

Comment: [We need to define a Q&A here on meta and link to that from the blog to indicate what are good and what are poor posts](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2426787#2426787)